# python33.dll not found Error while using Python4Delphi component

Tags: python, delphi, python4delphi

I'm working on a project with Python4Delphi component and also i want to use embedded version of python which is better to use as needs no installation.
I've set the correct path and filename to python310.dll in the appropriate properties but no chance to run properly and always getting the

```
Error 87: Could not open Dll "python33.dll"

Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit.
```

i also added the directory of the dll to environment variables still no luck. whats wrong?
(python and delphi 10.4 project both are 32bit versions, windows 10 64bit)

Comment: You write about using "python310.dll", but the error message is about a "python33.dll"!?

Comment: exactly! don't know wtf!

Comment: So then why do you think you need to provide  a Python 3.10 DLL? Did you try to provide a Python 3.3 DLL?

Comment: Coz i have 3.10 installed no need for 3.3 and thats weird

Comment: But the Delphi component seems to need 3.3!

Comment: Ensure your bitness of the installed Python matches the target platform bitness

Answer (score 1):

just set the propery "UseLastKnownVersion" of PythonEngine Component to false, the "python33.dll not found " will disapper

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Reinstall python worked for me. But this time i maked sure that was installing the same architecture that i was compiling the code to.
I reinstall python 3.10 on 32bits and worked for me, cuz i was compiling on win32

Comment: This wasn't my case but this surely helps someone, Thanks mate.

Comment: That fixed it for me too. I had installed Python 64 bit, but was compiling my Delphi app EXE as 32 bit

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in pythonengine.pas. on line 9075 change

```
MinorVersion := PythonVersion[3];
```

to

```
MinorVersion := StrToInt(copy(PythonVersion, 3, length(PythonVersion) - 2));
```

the MinorVersion is incorrectly set to 1 for version 3.10.

Comment: This does  not appear to be the case in May 2022 (Python 3.10, and P4D from the current code base)